# Elasticsearch query scores all documents 1.0. Why?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm using ElasticSearch 2.4.1.  When I execute the following query, all documents are scored 1.0.  Why?

I get the same behavior if I remove the "bool" and just do a match on one field.

Query:

```
{
    "query" : 
    {   
        "bool": {
            "must" : [
                {"match" : { "last" : { "query" :  "SMITH" , fuzziness: 2.0}} }
            ],
        "should" : [
            {"match" : {"first" :{ "query" :  "JOE", fuzziness: 1.0, boost: 99.0}}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Explain for one match gives me:

```
1.0 = sum of:
  1.0 = ConstantScore(+(last:1mith^0.8 last:1smith^0.8 last:4mith^0.8 last:amith^0.8 last:asmith^0.8 last:bsmith^0.8 last:csmith^0.8 last:dsmith^0.8 last:emith^0.8 last:esmith^0.8 last:fsmith^0.8 last:hmith^0.8 last:hsmith^0.8 last:imith^0.8 last:ismith^0.8 last:jmith^0.8 last:jsmith^0.8 last:ksmith^0.8 last:lsmith^0.8 last:msith^0.8 last:msmith^0.8 last:nsmith^0.8 last:omith^0.8 last:osmith^0.8 last:psmith^0.8 last:qsmith^0.8 last:rsmith^0.8 last:saith^0.8 last:samith^0.8 last:scmith^0.8 last:seith^0.8 last:shith^0.8 last:simith^0.8 last:simth^0.8 last:skith^0.8 last:slith^0.8 last:smaith^0.8 last:smath^0.8 last:smdith^0.8 last:smeth^0.8 last:smfith^0.8 last:smich^0.8 last:smidh^0.8 last:smidth^0.8 last:smieth^0.8 last:smigh^0.8 last:smiht^0.8 last:smiih^0.8 last:smiith^0.8 last:smith) (first:aoe^0.6666666 first:bjoe^0.6666666 first:boe^0.6666666 first:coe^0.6666666 first:djoe^0.6666666 first:doe^0.6666666 first:eoe^0.6666666 first:foe^0.6666666 first:goe^0.6666666 first:hoe^0.6666666 first:ioe^0.6666666 first:j0e^0.6666666 first:jae^0.6666666 first:jbe^0.6666666 first:jce^0.6666666 first:jee^0.6666666 first:jeo^0.6666666 first:jge^0.6666666 first:jhe^0.6666666 first:jhoe^0.6666666 first:jie^0.6666666 first:jioe^0.6666666 first:jke^0.6666666 first:jle^0.6666666 first:jme^0.6666666 first:jne^0.6666666 first:jnoe^0.6666666 first:joa^0.6666666 first:joae^0.6666666 first:job^0.6666666 first:jobe^0.6666666 first:joc^0.6666666 first:joce^0.6666666 first:jod^0.6666666 first:jode^0.6666666 first:joe first:joea^0.6666666 first:joeb^0.6666666 first:joec^0.6666666 first:joed^0.6666666 first:joee^0.6666666 first:joef^0.6666666 first:joeg^0.6666666 first:joeh^0.6666666 first:joei^0.6666666 first:joej^0.6666666 first:joek^0.6666666 first:joel^0.6666666 first:joem^0.6666666 first:joen^0.6666666)^99.0), product of:
    1.0 = boost
    1.0 = queryNorm
  0.0 = match on required clause, product of:
0.0 = # clause
0.0 = weight(_type:mytype in 327) [], result of:
  0.0 = score(doc=327,freq=1.0), with freq of:
    1.0 = termFreq=1.0
```

Type mapping:

```
{
  "ourindex1": {
    "mappings": {
      "people": {
        "properties": {        
          "city": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "first": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "last": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "middle": {
            "type": "string"
          },
         "state": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "street": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "suffix": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "suite": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "territory": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "zip5": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Simplified Reproduction:

1. Download clean version of elasticsearch 2.4.1 and start it up
2. Create new index with:

   POST /newindex/people

   {"first" : "JOE", "last": "SMITH", "street" : "1 FIRST STREET", "city" : "LOS ANGELES", "state" : "CA", "middle" : ""}
3. Issue the following query:

   { "query" : {"match" : { "last"  : { "query" : "SMITHX", fuzziness: 1.0} } }}

When I do this, document returned is scored 1.0 and explain says something about ConstantScore.

Edit 2:  It appears my reproduction steps included an unintentional lie

The library my app uses to communicate with elasticsearch (elastic4s), appears to mangle the query so that it becomes:

```
{"query" : { "query" : {"match" : { "last" : { "query" : "SMITHX", fuzziness: 1.0} } }}}
```

(Note that extra "query."  This mangled query returns the results I'd expect, but with score = 1.0.)  I thought I had already tried executing the query directly with curl, but evidently not.

Comment: I have tried the same query and seems working for me. Could you post some of your data?

Comment: @JianpingLiu I added reproduction steps that include some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of double **query** keyword. So, basically it working like this - inner **query** selects hits and produce something like this:

```
{
    "took": 7,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.30685285,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "people",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.30685285,
                "_source": {
                    "first": "JOHN",
                    "last": "SMITHS",
                    "street": "2 SECOND STREET",
                    "city": "LA",
                    "state": "CA",
                    "middle": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "people",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.30685282,
                "_source": {
                    "first": "JOE",
                    "last": "SMITH",
                    "street": "1 FIRST STREET",
                    "city": "LOS ANGELES",
                    "state": "CA",
                    "middle": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

which is fully correct response with proper score, but then the second **query** appears, which didn't change result set, but only "eat" the score and replace it with 1.0. So, you need to fix your usage of **elastic4s**

Comment: Yeah.  Just in case someone arrives here via google: I was doing ```search in ("index" -> type") rawQuery("{query: { bool : ... }}")```  I should have been doing: ```search in ("index" -> "type") rawQuery("{bool:...}")```